# Error while inserting Item into DynamoBD with SQS-Lambda integration

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-sqs

I have created a Lambda function which puts an Item in the DynamoDB table using Node.js 10.x. The Lambda function has been integrated with SQS Queue via trigger. When I put a message in the Queue the Lambda is invoked, but is throwing an error while inserting an Item in the DynamoDB table.

Message -> SQS -> Lambda -> DynamoDB

I am passing the TableName and the Item as the input to the DynamoDB put method. But, the CloudWatch Logs says that TableName and Item parameters are missing.  Below are the code snippets and the screenshots.

I did spend a good amount of time, but not able to get around the problem. Could someone help me?

**Lambda Code**

```
console.log('Loading function');

var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var dynamo = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {

    console.log('Received event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
    event.Records.forEach(record => {
      const { body } = record;
      console.log("Input to DynamoAPI :", body);
      dynamo.put(body, callback);
    });

  return {};
}
```

**Message that goes into the Queue**

```
{
  "TableName": "user-transaction",
  "Item" : {
    "transaction-id": 1
  }
}
```

**Error message from the CloudWatch**

[image]

Comment: It seems correct, can you add the definition of your dynamoDb table?
Have you added the transaction-id as the key?

Comment: @desoss I created a 'user-transaction' table with 'transaction-id' as the partition key, but I don't think it has to do anything with the table structure. It's failing at the validation and is not hitting the database. Without the table also I would be getting the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did not try this out, but it looks to me like there is a missing `JSON.parse()` around the body variable in the dynamo put invocation.

From what I remember, SQS stringifies the body and it is not parsed automatically.
The following answer which I found on SO sums this up perfectly: [1].

#### References

[1] https://stackoverflow.com/a/56925968/10473469

Comment: Martin - adding the JSON.parse() helped me - Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I checked a similar lambda of my own thats successfully doing a put.

```
var params = {
                TableName: dynamoUserTableName,
                Item:{
                    "userId" : { S: event.request.userAttributes.sub},
                    "email" : { S: event.request.userAttributes.email},
                    "userName" : { S: event.userName},
                    "createdDate" : { S: createdDate },
                    "version" : { N: '1'}
                }
            };
        console.log(params);
        dynamodb.putItem(params, function(err, data) {...
```

Here is the output from my console just before the put

```
{ TableName: 'Users',
  Item:
   { userId: { S: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' },
     email: { S: 'test@example.co.uk' },
     userName: { S: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' },
     createdDate: { S: '2020-05-02T07:49:23.478' },
     version: { N: '1' } } }
```

I note there are no quotes around my attribute names, maybe this is an issue?

Comment: Removing the quotes around the attributes names didn't help. I am also able to put the message just invoking the Lambda function. When I invoke the Lambda by putting message in the Queue that's when thing start breaking. Have you tried it out.